# How do you mixin functionality to each step of an iterative procedure with Scala?

Tags: scala, design-patterns

I am working on an optimization procedure in Scala and am looking for advice on how to structure my problem. The procedure takes one step at a time, so I've naively modelled the problem using a `Step` class:

```
class Step(val state:State) {
  def doSomething = ...
  def doSomethingElse = ...
  def next:Step = ... // produces the next step in the procedure
}
```

Each step in the procedure is represented by the immutable `Step` class whose constructor is given the state produced by the previous step and whose `next` method produces a subsequent `Step` instance. The basic idea is then to wrap this with `Iterator[Step]` so steps can be taken until the optimization converges. Although a bit simplistic, this works well for the vanilla case.

Now, however, I need to add various extensions to the algorithm, and I need to arbitrarily mixin these extensions depending on the problem being optimized. Normally this would be accomplished with the stackable trait pattern but this approach poses issues for this problem. Here is an example of two would-be extensions:

```
trait FeatureA extends Step {
  // Extension-specific state passed from step to step
  val aState:FeatureAState = ...

  // Wrap base methods to extend functionality
  abstract override def doSomething = { ...; super.doSomething(); ... }
}

// Just like Feature A
trait FeatureB extends Step {
  val bState:FeatureBState = ...
  abstract override def doSomething = { ...; super.doSomething(); ... }
}
```

Sometimes the optimization will need `FeatureA` mixed in, other times `FeatureB`, and sometimes both.

The main issue is that the `next` method of the base class doesn't know which extensions have been mixed in, so subsequently produced steps will not incorporate any extensions mixed into the initial one.

Also, each extension needs to pass its own state from step to step. In this example `FeatureAState`/`FeatureBState` instances are included in their respective traits, but without overriding the `next` method, `FeatureA` and `FeatureB` have no way to pass along their unique state. Overriding `next` in each trait cannot be done since there may be a combination of these extensions mixed in and each is only aware of itself.

So it seems I've painted myself into a corner here and am hoping someone has some insight for how to approach this with Scala. Which design pattern is most appropriate for this type of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in exploring the [F-bound polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) pattern.  This pattern allows you to define methods that return the current subtype in a trait or base class. Here is a simplified version of your example:

```
trait Step[T <: Step[T]] { self: T =>
    val name: String
    def next: T
}

case class BasicStep(name: String) extends Step[BasicStep] {
    def next = this.copy(name = name + "I")
}

case class AdvancedStep(baseName: String, iteration: Int) extends Step[AdvancedStep] {
    val name = s"$baseName($iteration)"
    def advancedFunction = println("foobar")
    def next = this.copy(iteration = iteration + 1)
}
```

So we've defined the basic `Step` trait, which has a `name` and a `next` method that returns whatever the self-type is of the extending class.  For example, the `next` method in `BasicStep` returns a `BasicStep`.  This allows us to iterate and use the subtype-specific overrides, as desired:

```
val basicSteps = Iterator.iterate(BasicStep("basic"))(_.next).take(3).toList
//basicSteps: List[BasicStep] = List(BasicStep(basic), BasicStep(basicI), BasicStep(basicII))

val advancedSteps = Iterator.iterate(AdvancedStep("advanced", 0))(_.next).take(3).toList
//advancedSteps: List[AdvancedStep] = List(AdvancedStep(advanced,0), AdvancedStep(advanced,1), AdvancedStep(advanced,2))
val names = advancedSteps.map(_.name)
//names: List[String] = List(advanced(0), advanced(1), advanced(2))
advancedSteps.last.advancedFunction
//foobar
```

If you want to mixin multiple types like this, you unfortunately can't use generics (you'll receive a "inherits different type instances of trait" error).  You can, however, use abstract type members to express the F-bound polymorphism:

```
trait Step { self =>
    type Self <: Step { type Self = self.Self }
    val name: String
    def next: Self
}

trait Foo extends Step {
    val fooMarker = "foo"
}
trait Bar extends Step {
    val barMarker = "bar"
}

case class FooBar(name: String) extends Foo with Bar {
    override type Self = FooBar
    def next = this.copy(name + "I")
}
```

Then `FooBar` instances will have the methods on `Foo` and on `Bar`:

```
val fooBar = FooBar("foobar").next.next
fooBar.barMarker //"bar"
fooBar.fooMarker //"foo"
fooBar.name //"fooNameII"
```

Notice that the name comes from `Foo`, since it was mixed in first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ben. This is more or less what I have right now. The thing is I want to be able to mixin both `BasicStep` and `AdvancedStep` simultaneously.  Each trait wraps any pertinent methods/vals in the base class in order to add functionality, no problem here. The crux seems to be the fact that each step produces the next, and the mixins have no way of incorporating themselves (and their state) into the newly constructed `Step`. It seems like I've got to take a radically different approach.

Comment: Another option I've been pondering would entail changing `Step` to a trait and leaving `next` unimplemented (as you suggest). Now our entire hierarchy contains only traits.  Then, for each combination of features, create a concrete class mixing everything in and implementing `next` there.  I think this would work but the idea of creating a concrete class for every combination of features seems awkward.

Comment: Hi Ben, I gave the updated approach a try and while it does work I’m not happy with having to create a concrete class for every combination of mixins. This just creates too much boilerplate and it gets worse for each additional trait. I ended up refactoring my code to avoid the issue altogether and, though not ideal, I’m marking this as the solution as it may be an acceptable route for others. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad I could provide any help.  If you'd like to share your solution as an answer here, I'd be curious to see it (if it's still a relevant answer to the original question).

Comment: I was able to work around the problem by modularizing the fundamental computations of each step and allowing different implementations to be plugged into the `Step` class instead of overriding it directly. This way `Step.next` simply passes these modules to the next `Step` instance. So far I'm pleased with how clean and simple this worked out and hopefully it'll prove general enough for future extensions too.

Comment: Sounds like a better solution.